# Checking block details in tezos

Tags: node, tezos-client

While running the tezos node, i was checking block details using RPC call(:8732/chains/main/blocks/). It will give block details. After 10 mins, if I check it will gone. The output is in empty page.

Answer (score 1):

`curl http://127.0.0.1/chains/main/blocks/head` should always return data, and should always return the most recent block. If you are not getting data, check the logs of your node to make sure there are not any other issues.

Comment: curl http://127.0.0.1/chains/main/blocks/blockhash. Getting block details,but those block details  are not shown after 10 mins. Kindly give me the solution

Comment: Have you checked the logs of your node after 10m? Run `curl -vv` to check if you are getting 503 or 404 errors.